# proof about irreducible polynomials with complex roots in Q

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, roots

I need some idea to proof the next statement.

Let $\alpha$ and $\beta$ two complex roots from irreducible polynomials $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ in $\mathbb{Q}$. Let $K=\mathbb{Q(\alpha)}$ and $L=\mathbb{Q(\beta)}$. Show that $f$ is irreducible in $L[x]$ if and only if $g$  is irreducible in $K[x]$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From 
$$ [K(\beta):K][K:\Bbb Q]=[\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta):\Bbb Q]=[L(\alpha):L][L:\Bbb Q],$$
we see that $$[K(\beta):K]=\deg g\iff [L(\alpha):L]=\deg f.$$

Comment: how you know that $[K(β):K]$= $degg$ ?